# MySQL query to randomise rows and then autoincrement a column

Tags: mysql, random, row

I'm trying to make a query that randomises the order of id and place them into a temp id column, but only where a status column is marked as '2'

Table starts out like this:

```
id       tempid     status
1     |    -1    |    2
2     |    -1    |    2
3     |    -1    |    2
4     |    -1    |    2
5     |    -1    |    2
6     |    -1    |    2
7     |    -1    |    1
8     |    -1    |    1
9     |    -1    |    2
```

And then then after the query it would have done something like this:

```
id       tempid     status
1     |    2     |    2
2     |    9     |    2
3     |    1     |    2
4     |    5     |    2
5     |    3     |    2
6     |    4     |    2
7     |    -1    |    1
8     |    -1    |    1
9     |    6     |    2
```

Any help would be much appreciated :D

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SET @newTempID=0;
UPDATE ttable 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT id, @newTempId:=@newTempId+1 AS tempid ,status
   FROM 
     (SELECT id,status FROM ttable WHERE status=2 ORDER BY RAND()) t 
  ) t2 ON ttable.id=t2.id 
SET ttable.tempid=t2.tempid WHERE ttable.status=2;
```

It looks horrible because it is 6am and I have not slept, but I tested it and it works. Just note, you must run both queries for it to work. Please mark as solved if this does in fact solve your problem.

Comment: Worked a charm after putting my table name in, changing ttable.st=2 to ttable.status=2 on the last line and putting ' around all of the status columns.. forgot that was a reserved word.. :S thank you very much for your quick reply!